# How to perform function arguments register allocation with the llvm framework?

Tags: c++, llvm

I am working on a debug symbol extractor and I need to extract function arguments name and register location from dwarf and pdb. Dwarf includes the register location and that is easy, but pdb only offers the calling convention name and the argument number. Is there a way to perform regalloc on a function arguments provided its calling conventions, without having to perform the all code gen, with llvm?

I know that the all informations regarding calling convetions are kept inside the tablegen files, but that does not really help to find out how  to do it, the generated files don't show up in the documentation, and it does not seems that there is simple function or class to do that.

If it is impossible or hard to do it with llvm, is there any other way to get that information with well known c++ libraries?